# python sqlalchemy: get empty record if none

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables:
User:  id, name
Phone: id, user_id, phone_num

When executing query:

```
Query([User, Phone].select_from(User).join(Phone, Phone.user_id == User.id).filter(User.id == the_user)
```

It returns the record if exists.  My question is that when there are no record matches, how can I returns something like:
{'id': None, 'user_id': None, 'phone_num': None}

Comment: By no record matches, do you mean a User with no matching Phone?  Or the case when there is no user matching `the_user` at all?

Comment: User.id == the_user return False, which means the User is not found.

Comment: Use something like `session.query(...).first()` and if it is `None` then just return the empty case.  But also if `the_user` is an id it is more clear to name it `the_user_id` otherwise it looks like you are comparing `User.id` to an object.  Which would not work.